# Is CRC32 exactly 32-bits?

Tags: calculation, crc32

Is `CRC32` exactly 32-bits, or is it **maximum** of 32-bits?

I mean if it can be randomly equal to e.g. 140 (8-bits is enough).

Comment: is uint32 with value of `0` 32-bit wide? yes it is, even if single bit is enough to store its value.

Comment: @rkosegi Yes sir, you're right, but I mean if all values of CRC32 start with a 1 (representing exactly 32-bits) or not.

Comment: Only 50% of all values will start with 1. If all of them start with 1 then you don't have full 32 bit range, only 31 bit.

Comment: I thought it would return a value between 2B and 4B (exactly 32-bits), in decimal. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is always a 32-bit value. Since the range covers from 0 to 2^32-1, then you may get a value that can be represented by 31 bits (50% chance), 30 bits (25% chance), etc.

Comment: So you mean the chance of getting a `32-bits` value over let's say 100B numbers, is about 50%, 25% to be `31-b`, and so on? Doesn't the CRC32 return number, for example, number `1` (`1-bit`) have the same chance as a return of number `140` (`8-bits`)?

Comment: It's 100% 32-bit numbers, but only 50% will require 32-bit to represent. Let's say you're using 3 bits, the result ranges from 0 to 7 for a total of 8 numbers. 4(100) to 7(111), a total of 4 numbers (50%) require 3 bit, the rest 50% only require 2 bit, only 25% chance to get numbers that only require 1 bit (0 and 1)

Comment: > "It's 100% 32-bit numbers, but only 50% will require 32-bit to represent."

This was great. So, How can I make an unavailable number for a default CRC32 (I want no one can brute-force it)

Comment: If you want the output to always require 32-bit, you're reducing the possible output range and help brute-forcing instead. https://github.com/nfirvine/crc-collision mentions it take mere 6 hours with Python (certainly not speed devil by any means) on a consumer laptop, single-threaded, to find a collision for all possible values, six years ago. Probably less than an hour in a beefy desktop with parallelized assembly code today. If you want security, use cryptographic hashing algorithms. CRC isn't even meant for security in the first place.

Comment: I wish the problem was that. I have to have the same algorithm on Java (as a server) and c (for `ESP8266`), and wanted to use this. passwords are in a range of 1000 to 9999, and we want to have a default hash that no one can brute-force. What do you suggest?

Comment: You do not need to use brute force to create CRC collisions. CRCs are linear functions over GF(2). It is easy and blindingly fast to solve for solutions using simple algebra. See [spoof](https://github.com/madler/spoof) for an example.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi If you want a hash that no one can spoof, then _do not use any CRC_! Use a cryptographic hash designed for that very purpose, such as SHA-256.